# How to fix this reducebykey transformation issue in my pyspark code?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am little stuck as how to get this value correct. Below is my sample data:

```
col_name,Category,SegmentID,total_cnt,PercentDistribution
city,ANTIOCH,1,1,15
city,ARROYO GRANDE,1,1,15
state,CA,1,3,15
state,NZ,1,4,15
```

[image]

**I am trying to get the output dataframe as :**

[image]

**I could arrive till this. Need your help here.**

```
    from pyspark.sql.types import StructType,StructField,StringType,IntegerType
    import json

    join_df=spark.read.csv("/tmp/testreduce.csv",inferSchema=True, header=True)
    jsonSchema = StructType([StructField("Name", StringType())
                           , StructField("Value", IntegerType())
                           , StructField("CatColName", StringType())
                           , StructField("CatColVal", StringType())
                        ])
    def reduceKeys(row1, row2):
            row1[0].update(row2[0])
            return row1

    res_df=join_df.rdd.map(lambda row: ("Segment " + str(row[2]), ({row[1]: row[3]},row[0],row[4])))\
.reduceByKey(lambda x, y: reduceKeys(x, y))\
.map(lambda row: (row[0], row[1][2],row[1][1], json.dumps(row[1][0]))).toDF(jsonSchema)
```

**My Current code output:**

It is not grouping the data correctly based on segment id and CatColName.

[image]

Comment: Is it necessary that the name is segment 1? or is it possible to add additional values there

Comment: Yeah its necessary because after the dataframe gets created i am planning to generate a json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the reduceByKey takes your generated string `Segment 1` into account and this is equal for city and state. If you add the `col_name` in the beginning it works as expected but you receive a different name in your result. This can be changed with a regular expression

```py
res_df=test_df.rdd.map(lambda row: ("Segment " + str(row[2]) +" " + str(row[0]), ({row[1]: row[3]},row[0],row[4])))\
.reduceByKey(lambda x, y: reduceKeys(x, y))\
.map(lambda row: (row[0], row[1][2],row[1][1], json.dumps(row[1][0]))).toDF(jsonSchema).withColumn("name",regexp_extract(col("name"),"(\w+\s\d+)",1))

res_df.show(truncate=False)
```

Output:

```
+---------+-----+----------+----------------------------------+
|name     |Value|CatColName|CatColVal                         |
+---------+-----+----------+----------------------------------+
|Segment 1|15   |city      |{"ANTIOCH": 1, "ARROYO GRANDE": 1}|
|Segment 1|15   |state     |{"CA": 3, "NZ": 4}                |
+---------+-----+----------+----------------------------------+
```

The final regexp_extract is only needed to restore the original name.